# Python numpad error when trying to press the numbers

Tags: python, pygtk

Hey guys im a beginner in python and im doing a numberpad that shows number in a textbox.

The GUI works and everything, but when I wanna press a button I get this message:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\E-net\Documents\PythonT9\python.py", line 5, in press
    num = entry.Box.get_text()
AttributeError: 'gtk.Entry' object has no attribute 'Box'
```

And I cant figur out why :(

The code

```
import gtk

def press(widget):

    num = entry.box.get_text()
    pnum = widget.get_label()
    entry.set_text(num+pnum)

def send_press(widget):
    print "dialing:" + entry.get_text()

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

box = gtk.VBox()
win.add(box)

entry = gtk.Entry()
box.pack_start(entry,False)

table = gtk.Table(2,2, gtk.TRUE)

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"#",0,"*"]
x = 0
y = 0

for i in a: 
    button = gtk.Button(str(i))
    button.connect("clicked",press)
    table.attach(button,x,x+1,y,y+1 )

    x+=1
    if x > 2:
        x = 0
        y+=1


box.pack_start(table)

send = gtk.Button("SEND")
send.connect("clicked",send_press)
box.pack_start(send)
win.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward - just change:

`num = entry.box.get_text()`

to

`num = entry.get_text()`

BTW, you could have solved this "mystery" in cca 30seconds if you just looked at the pygtk documentation.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a beginner to this.. I really tried to look.. 

I appriciate taking your time sir.

Comment: No apology required, sir :) Just promise me to add bookmark here: (http://pygtk.org/reference.html)